# Drools: How to use timed sliding windows without entry point

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine

I'm trying to use sliding windows and i just can't get it working without entry points

This is what i want

```
rule
    when
        $testPoints: Points()

        Boolean(booleanValue == false) from accumulate (
        PU(
            value = "test"
        ) over window : time(10s) from $testPoints.points,
        init(boolean b = true;),
        action(b = false),
        result(b)
        )
    then
     ......
end
```

I've tried testing this and everything works except the "from $testPoints.points".  I don't want to use an entry point for this and $testPoints.points is an array of PU so my intuition says that this should be fine but its not.  When i try to create my kieSession it just throws a null pointer error.

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: I suppose that this `PU[]` array does not contain facts, so you cannot reason over them using a sliding window. You need events, and each event must be  inserted as a separate fact.

Comment: @laune i have declared PU as an event with timestamp, so $testPoints.points is an array of events

Comment: But you did not insert them as facts. You cannot use a sliding window except over a set of facts. - If the timestamp is a field of class PU you can compare that to the current time (using a static method or whatever).